# Why won't my server accept files larger then 2MB?

Tags: php, file-upload, asihttprequest, vps

I have a VPS that runs XAMPP and gives service to an iPhone App that I made.

I used **ASIHTTPRequest** to upload files to the server.

The App sends files to the server, and the server accept only those who are lighter then 2MB.

I also checked with Wireshark and found this warning:

**PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in c:/xxx/index.php in line 2**

in line 2 I wrote: **session_start();**

in my theory they are 2 things that block big files from entering my server:

1. Some kind of file size limit
2. Some kind of time limit per action

I really need help on this one. Thanks!

Comment: What code is in the index.php file?

Comment: It is a limit on the duration of a script in order to prevent some bad written scripts (or infinite loops) to crash the server. It has nothing to with filesize...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the settings in your `php.ini` file which, when running XAMPP, can be found in the `*root*/php/` directory.

```
#Make sure file uploads are turned on
file_uploads = On

#Change the max upload size to 100Mb
upload_max_filesize = 100M

#Change the max post size to 100Mb
post_max_size = 100M

#Change the max upload time to 900seconds
max_input_time = 900

#This is where you are seeing your problem as the script execution is timing out.
#Change the max execution time of the script to 900 seconds
max_execution_time = 900
```

Comment: Thanks @BrianMansell, you know you can edit other peoples questions?

Comment: it was the input time that was driving me crazy!

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Unfortunately, a one character change is below the minimum. I didn't want to introduce unneeded additional changes to their comment.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following lines in your `php.ini` file:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 300
```

You might have to restart your server afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The error says: `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`

This makes me think that your internet-connection is slow, thus the upload is taking more than the `max_execution_time`

To see what the `max_execution_time` currently is:

`$maxtime = ini_get(max_execution_time);`

`echo $maxtime;`

To make the `max_execution_time` bigger for the current page, enter this line on top of your PHP-file:
`ini_set("max_execution_time", 600);?>`

Answer (score 0):

Put at the topo of your index.php:

```
<?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 180); //Put the number of seconds that you want
```

The `upload_max_filesize` can't be change in runtime, so you need to increase this value in your `php.ini`