# Uploading/Saving videos not working in PHP

Tags: php, video

If a user inputs "0" in the "media_type" text box, it runs the image upload code and if you put "1" it runs the video upload code. The problem is with the video section because when i upload a video, it doesn't display anything. But when i input an image, and go to the image section, it works. Here is my code

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $media_type = addslashes($_POST['media_type']);

    if($media_type !=0 && $media_type !=1){

        die (json_encode([
        "Status" => " Failed",
        "Message" => " Error 404"
    ]));
        exit;
    }

    if(@getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])==false){

        echo json_encode([

            "Status" => " Failed",
            "Message" => " No file selected..."
        ]);
        exit;
    }

    if(@getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) ==FALSE || $_POST['user_id'] == "" || $_POST['media_type'] =="" || $_POST['category1'] ==""){

        echo json_encode([
            "Status" => "Failed",
            "Message" => "There were values missing"

        ]);

    die("");
    }


function imageUpload(){
    $userid = addslashes($_POST['user_id']);
    $category1 = addslashes($_POST['category1']);
    $category2 = addslashes($_POST['category2']);
    $category3 = addslashes($_POST['category3']);


//if file is there

    $target = "images/";

    $target_file = addslashes($target . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));

    if(file_exists($target_file)){

        echo json_encode([
            "Status" => " Failed",
            "Message" => " Sorry, file already exists..."
        ]);
        exit;
    }
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
{

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($db, "magicsever");

    if(mysqli_connect_error()){

        die ("Database connection error");
    }

$image = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$name = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);    

$sql = "INSERT INTO classified_images (`user_id`,`image`, `img_path`, `img_category_1`,`img_category_2`, `img_category_3`)VALUES('$userid','$image','$name','$category1','$category2','$category3')";
$final = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
"Status" => "OK",
"userId" => $_POST["user_id"]
]);
}else{

echo json_encode([
"Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
"Status" => "Error",
"userId" => $_POST["user_id"]
]);

}   
}

function videoUpload(){
    $userid = addslashes($_POST['user_id']);
    $category1 = addslashes($_POST['category1']);
    $category2 = addslashes($_POST['category2']);
    $category3 = addslashes($_POST['category3']);
    // Check if file was submited

    $target = "videos/";

    $target_file = addslashes($target . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]));



    // Check if file already exists
    if(file_exists($target_file)){

        echo json_encode([
            "Status" => " Failed",
            "Message" => " Sorry, file already exists..."
        ]);
        exit;
    }

    // Check file size not > 500Mb
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 500000000){

        echo json_encode([

            "Status" => " Failed",
            "Message" => " Sorry, file is too large."
        ]);
        exit;
    }

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){

            $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysqli_select_db($db, "magicsever");

    if(mysqli_connect_error()){

        die ("Database connection error");
    }

    $video = addslashes($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
        $name = addslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO classified_videos (`user_id`, `vid_path`, `vid_category_1`, `vid_category_2`, `vid_category_3`, `video`)VALUES('$userid','$name','$category1','$category2','$category3','$video')";
    $final = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

            echo json_encode([

                "Status" => " Success",
                "Message" => " The file ". basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
                "userId" => $_POST["user_id"]
            ]);
        }else{

            echo json_encode([

                "Status" => " Failed",
                "Message" => " Sorry, there was an error uploaded your file"
            ]);
            exit;
        }

    //Connect to database


}
    if($media_type ==0){

        imageUpload();
    }else if($media_type ==1){

        videoUpload();
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file">

<br></br>
<input type="text" name="user_id" placeholder="User id...">
<br></br>
<input type="text" name="media_type" placeholder="(0)Image...(1)Video">
<br></br>
<input type="text" name="category1" placeholder="MediaTag#1...">
<br></br>
<input type="text" name="category2" placeholder="MediaTag#2...">
<br></br>
<input type="text" name="category3" placeholder="MediaTag#3...">
    <br></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload">


</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of images cross 2MB upload size if you have upload more than 2MB data increase the size "File upload size "  from php.ini file

Comment: Thank you, i researched it more and found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734184/why-wont-my-server-accept-files-larger-then-2mb which helped

Answer (score 1):

In case of video, your control for image size is always giving false (or nonsensical values):

```
if(@getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])==false){
```

That is why you are receiving the "No file selected" message.
Check if you are getting video or images and run that control just in the right case.

As you can read in the documentation [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) :

> Caution
>   This function expects filename to be a valid image file. If a non-image file is supplied, it may be incorrectly detected as an image and the function will return successfully, but the array may contain nonsensical values.

Comment: OHH so the problem was the "getimagesize"? I removed it and i am still have the problem.

Comment: For sure you have a problem with getimagesize() as states the documentation.  I also tested the script and uploading a file mp4 always gives false. I see you had also a size upload issue that you already fixed. Next time please provide the error you are getting to help community understand your issue.